# Problems Aligning cell with UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

The problem is that when loading the scroll of the table the text is on the left and when finished loading the scroll goes to the right and you can see the change in position, this looks bad and I looked into other answer but nothing worked for me.

[Problems aligning text UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201678/problems-aligning-text-with-uitableviewcell)

[Aligning text in UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24841033/aligning-text-in-uitableview/24841582#24841582)

[Centro Alinear texto en el problema UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467288/center-align-text-in-uitableviewcell-problem)

I have a normal cell in tableView, when I want to align it text to right I use:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSDictionary *mensaje = [self.mensajes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *tipoFR = [mensaje objectForKey:@"emisor"];
    NSString *idUsuario = @"10";

    if ([tipoFR isEqualToString:idUsuario]) {

        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        NSString *chat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@  ", [mensaje objectForKey:@"mensaje"]];

        //Move text to the right
        [self performSelector:@selector(alignText:) withObject:cell afterDelay:0.0];

        cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
        cell.detailTextLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
        cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"";
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(131 / 255.0 ) green:( 224 / 255.0 ) blue:( 140 / 255.0 ) alpha:1];
        cell.textLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0f;
        [cell.textLabel setClipsToBounds:YES];
        cell.textLabel.text = chat;
        cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;

        return cell;

    }else{

        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cellda";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
        cell.detailTextLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
        cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"";

        cell.textLabel.text = [mensaje objectForKey:@"mensaje"];
        cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0;

        return cell;
    }  
}

- (void)alignText:(UITableViewCell*)cell{
    CGRect frame = cell.textLabel.frame;
    frame.origin.x = cell.frame.size.width - (frame.size.width + 10.0);
    cell.textLabel.frame = frame;

    frame = cell.detailTextLabel.frame;
    frame.origin.x = cell.frame.size.width - (frame.size.width + 10.0);
    cell.detailTextLabel.frame = frame;
    [cell setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

> loading scroll issue image

[image: loading scroll]

> loading scroll

[image: loaded scroll]

Comment: you are aligning it youself  in 
 [self performSelector:@selector(alignText:) withObject:cell afterDelay:0.0];

Comment: just comment this line it will stop moving the position

Comment: Or, if you want to have the text on the right, just align it to the right without the delay,

Comment: What is your "mensaje" value ? Please give me its value.

Comment: I want to align the cell without the delay and I do it with the
[self performSelector: @selector (alignText :) withObject: cell afterDelay: 0.0];

But it takes to load right by the scroll as I can avoid that delay because the movement is seen